# Getting a value from a text box in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, search, save, laravel-5.8

I can,t get the textbox value to a variable from the form

I have tried almost every option possible to get this right but nothing worked

> search.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
    @section('content')

    <form action="/student/searchshow" method="POST" role="search">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"> 

                <a href="{{url('student/search/')}}" class="btn btn-default">search</a>  

        </div>   
     </form>
    @stop
```

> StudentController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\student;//to access the views in student
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
  public function searchshow()
  {
    return view('student.search');
   }

 public function search()
    {
      $name = Input::get('name');

       dd($name);
    }   
}
```

> web.php

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('student/searchshow', 'StudentController@searchshow');

Route::post('student/search', 'StudentController@search');
```

when i try to get the value to a variable from the form(search.blade.php) it always gives the result null

Comment: why are you using this `<a href="{{url('student/search/')}}" class="btn btn-default">search</a>` inside the form

Answer (score 0):

In Route, URL is

```
Route::post('student/search', 'StudentController@search');
```

But In form

```
<form action="/student/searchshow" method="POST" role="search">
```

You should change

```
<form action="/student/search" method="POST" role="search">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="input-group">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"> 
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">search</button>  
    </div>   
</form>
```

Comment: yes it worked thanks for the response. but there is another issue how can i get the data from the form to the variable in my controller when the search button is clicked(which is inside the form)

Comment: @dasundevinda when the search button is clicked then all data of form should send to controller because It's submit button. `public function search(Request $request)` => you can get all data with code: `$data = $request->all();`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are sending POST request to action that accepts only get
you should change Form action to  'student/search'

and than you can get Posted data as in example below

```
....
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('name');
    ....
```

Here is link for documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests

Comment: yes it worked thanks for the response. but there is another issue how can i get the data from the form to the variable in my controller when the search button is clicked(which is inside the form)

Comment: <a href="{{url('student/search/')}}" class="btn btn-default">search</a>  
instead of <a> tag you should use <button type='submit'>Search</button>